# Unable to access some websites(Google) in android simulator behind proxy?

Tags: android-emulator, android-browser

I am unable to access to certain websites like www.google.com in android emulator. We are in a secured corporate  network and use proxy to connect to the internet. I tried by adding the http-proxy in the startup command, still the same problem. I am able to access certain sites like msn.com, and favicon is loading for almost all the sites, but still the browser says "The web page at  might be temporarily down". Please throw some light on this?